# Could not transfer artifact pom in gradle maven-publish plugin

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I use the gradle (2.9) **maven-publish** plugin to publish a file to a private nexus maven repo. The build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name "example-maven"
            url "https://..."
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {

            groupId 'com.example.karaf-utils'
            artifactId 'esa-bootstrapper'
            version '1.0.0'

            artifact source: "${projectDir}/kar/example.esa.bootstrapper.kar", extension: 'kar'

        }
    }
}
```

The kar file is correctly uploaded and in nexus I can see the expected xml descriptor:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.karaf-utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>esa-bootstrapper</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>kar</type>
</dependency>
```

but unfortunately, during the execution of the `publish` task, I get the following error:

```
gradle :com.example.karaf.subsys.bootstrap:publish
:com.example.karaf.subsys.bootstrap:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:com.example.karaf.subsys.bootstrap:publishMavenPublicationToexample-mavenRepository
Upload https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven/com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.kar
Upload https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven/com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.kar.sha1
Upload https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven/com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.kar.md5
Upload https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven/com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.pom
Could not transfer artifact com.example.karaf-utils:esa-bootstrapper:pom:1.0.0 from/to remote (https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven): Could not write to resource 'com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.pom'
:com.example.karaf.subsys.bootstrap:publishMavenPublicationToexample-mavenRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.example.karaf.subsys.bootstrap:publishMavenPublicationToexample-mavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'example-maven'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.example.karaf-utils:esa-bootstrapper:pom:1.0.0 from/to remote (https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven): Could not write to resource 'com/example/karaf-utils/esa-bootstrapper/1.0.0/esa-bootstrapper-1.0.0.pom'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

How could I fix this error?

Comment: if `https://nexus.dev.example.io/nexus/content/repositories/example-maven` really is the directory you expect to deploy, the issue is probably on your server: your user may not have write access.

Comment: The user seems to have write access: the kar file itself gets correctly uploaded by the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved: the point is I was trying to overwrite an existing pom file in nexus. I deleted the kar file but I forgot to remove the pom before running the gradle task.